# migration of androMDA to?

Tags: java, hibernate, uml, andromda

I would like to do a replace the actual working framework androMDA to another one which can give me the same features.
We use it to generate the code from UML (with magic draw UML) and we use the cartridges to map with the database (create hibernate files).
Does anyone know a framework or tool or eclipse plugin which could replace androMDA and that is free / open source?

thank you very much for any help.

Have a nice day.

Cecile.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct replacement, but [Eclipse EMF](http://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) is another example of a UML-like model to code generation framework.  It is free and open source.

EMF uses Ecore models which are similar to MOF models.  MOF is the core of OMG's MDA and effectively the core of UML.

The Eclipse modelling ecosystem includes lots of technologies including technologies that support serialization to XML (or XMI) and database persistence (including Hibernate).

Comment: I forgot to say that I which to reuse the xml model of androMDA or create the UML model from the generated classes (reverse engeneering).

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions today.

**You can either use** your class diagram model and generate the code from the xmi. The needed database would also be created. AndroMDA is really a good tool but because open source the investment is smaller than professional tools then using Blue Age or MIA Software is recommended. Both solution are really good and generate clean code. This could be used with hibernate 2 or 3 I believe.

**or** you can use a tool (e.g. Omondo EclipseUML 3.7 only) which will generate Java annotation directly from your diagram. This feature is only possible if you use Hibernate 3 in which annotations have replaced the xml description file of Hibernate 2.

I wold recommend not to spend to much time with EMF because this is too complex and not UML but more DSL oriented using its own metamodel. I did try it but the framework learning investment is too high compare to other alternatives.